# Is there a way to hide the side bar in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way to hide the side bar that shows you what line you're on in `Sublime Text 2`?

Here is the bar:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `"gutter":false` to user preferences.